# AS3 slideshow/playlist uploaded from a predefined XML-file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

Does anyone know any good tutoriols on how to create a "slideshow" or "playlist" in ActionScript3? The slide can be either a simple picture, a soundfile or a video.

I want to be able to jump back and forth in the slideshow/playlist, and also see how long a slide will be shown.

The playlist will be loaded from a pre-defined XML-file.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Please go at flashmo.com. you will findout the lots of free flash template for flash based website and as well as different slidshow, photogallery, video gallery and so many things...